Why when table is wrapped with fieldset x-scrolling does not work anymore?
With tailwindcss 3.4.1 I have define a table, like :
                <div class="my-0 mx-2 p-0 overflow-x-auto">
                    <table class="editor_listing_table mb-4">
                        <thead class="editor_listing_table_header">
                        <tr>
                        ...

and as the table is wrapped in overflow-x-auto class it has x-scrolling.
                        But when I add fieldset wrapping these div/table :

        <fieldset class="p-1 m-1 mb-6 bordered">
            <legend class="bordered">
                Your active tasks
            </legend>

                <div class="my-0 mx-2 p-0 overflow-x-auto d1">
                    <table class="editor_listing_table mb-4">
                        <thead class="editor_listing_table_header">
                        <tr>
                            ...
                            

x-scrolling does not work anymore and I do not know haw can I change fieldset to allow x-scrolling of table with data ?
UPDATED DATA :
I tried to put one more dive between            </legend> and <div class="my-0 mx-2 p-0 overflow-x-auto"> tags, trying to make wrapping div, like :
<fieldset class="p-1 m-1 mb-6 bordered inline-block">
<legend class="bordered">
    Your active tasks
</legend>

    <!-- I added a line with div below -->
<div class="flex flex-col grow w-full overflow-x-clip justify-start items-start border-blue-500">
    <div class="my-0 mx-2 p-0 overflow-x-auto d2">
        <table class="editor_listing_table mb-4">
            <thead class="editor_listing_table_header">

It did not help and I have no scrolling with fieldset above. Which classes must be within this div to salve my problem.

what is class d1 in the overflowed wrapper?

Oh, just debugging border

Please read UPDATED DATA
